# Using RabbitMQ build trigger in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rabbitmq, jenkins-plugins, build-triggers

I have setup a RabbitMQ server on a VM in my machine - I have verified through Rabbit MQ web client as well as python code that I am able to publish and receive messages in and out of a queue.

I have setup Jenkins in another VM. I have verified that from this machine I am able to publish/ subscribe messages using the RabbitMQ server.

I've installed RabbitMQ Build Trigger plugin and configured the Rabbit MQ queue in the settings section. I've also verified that the test connection is successful. The settings are as shown in [image: RMQ-1]

I've configured a test job and set the token in build trigger to "TOKEN", as shown in [image: RMQ-2]

I am publishing a message using RabbitMQ's management web front end, as shown in [image: RMQ-3]

The issue is that I don't see a build getting triggered on Jenkins - is there something I am missing in my setup?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the settings section that you added your username password? I cant even find that

Comment: Have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your jenkins project name. As per your message the name of your test project should be TestProject.